# How to save the installation of global package using package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

How to save the installation of global package using `package.json`?

I couldn't find any good solutions but I did this like below:

In `package.json` I added the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm install babel babel-cli -g"
},
```

It would run and install the above packages globally before installing all the dependencies and devDependencies in `package.json`.

But the problem would be that I would not be able to find out, are those packages installed globally in any of the machines.

Please help, if anyone have any better solution of this.

Comment: any good reason for install global packages on pre-install?

Comment: But without installing globally, I can't run them in CLI.

Comment: Note that the [babel instructions](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) _specifically recommend that you not install it globally_: "While you can install Babel CLI globally on your machine, it’s much better to install it locally project by project."

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad practice to force global install of a module. You can put `babel` and `babel-cli` in your devDependencies and then use them in your npm scripts :

```
{
  "build" : "babel src -d build"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.18.0"
}
```

Comment: But without installing globally, I can't run them in CLI.

Comment: You can using npm scripts like in my answer. You can by calling ``./node_modules/.bin/babel`` instead of  ``babel``. And of course you can install it globally but it should be a choice not a constraint as you pollute the developer's global environment.

Comment: @NazmulBasher if you want to use via CLI, you need to wire the setup via `bin`. Reference the setup of [this library](https://github.com/code-and-send/fol). Basically, set up `bin` in `package.json` as shown there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to run your package via CLI, you need to set up using [bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) approach.

Here's one of my libraries for example, [fol](https://github.com/code-and-send/fol). It is meant to be ran via command line only.

At the most minimal setup, you would wire both `main` and `bin` to the same JS file, for example, adding the following in `package.json`:

```
"main": "./bin/fol.js",
  "bin": {
    "fol": "./bin/fol.js"
  },
```

Then, put the files into `bin` folder for the same of consistency, everybody will  recognise that's CLI app stuff if it's in `/bin/`.